# How to properly reset a rxjs Interval?

Tags: angular, rxjs

**How to properly reset a rxjs Interval?**

```
...

ngOnInit(){
    this.timer = interval(this.SAVE_DELAY_TIMER);
    this.timer.subscribe((x => {
        this.onTimerEnd();
    }));
}


resetTimer(){
    //how to?
}
```

I need to reset my interval when a certain situation happens? Whats the apropriate way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to simply emit whenever a certain time period has passed without any "certain situation" occurring.  If that's the case, you can use [`debounceTime`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime).

Your "certain situation" could come from any observable source. For this example I'll use a BehaviorSubject triggered by a button click:

```js
  private certainSituation$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);

  private timer$ = this.certainSituation$.pipe(debounceTime(DURATION));
  
  private timerSub = this.timer$.subscribe(
    () => console.log('TIMER DONE')
  );

  situation() {
    this.certainSituation$.next();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76239182?devtoolsheight=80&file=src%2Fmain.ts) example.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a method to restart your timer as followed:

```
export class App {
  timer: Observable<any>;
  init = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor() {
    this.timer = this.init.pipe(
        // restart counter on every new reset
        switchMap(() => interval(this.SAVE_DELAY_TIMER))
    )
    this.timer.subscribe(console.log);
  }

  reset(){
     this.init.next(null)
  }
}
```

You can find more detail about switchMap [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function to init timer. In case interval already started, it would delete the progres and subscribe again to start from 0.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.timer = interval(this.SAVE_DELAY_TIMER);
    this.initTimer();
}

initTimer(){
    this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
    this.timerSub = this.timer.subscribe((x => {
        this.onTimerEnd();
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. One thing though, Wouldnt it be ? this.timerSub = interval(this.SAVE_DELAY_TIMER); Line 2

Comment: interval(this.SAVE_DELAY_TIMER) is just an Observable. When you subscribe to it a subscription instance is created. When you unsubscribe, that instance is then deleted. Just a general tip, keeping track of subscriptions is important, if you don´t unsubscribe from them it might create a memory leak since it will be running even if component that created it is destroyed. So in ngOnDestroy(){} of mentioned component I also would put this.timerSub.unsubscribe();